# accidentally opened the door enough

Tags: meaning, phrases

Can one say

1. He accidentally opened the door enough that they could see inside the office.
2. He accidentally opened the door enough so they could see inside the office.
3. He accidentally opened the door enough so that they could see inside the office.
4. He accidentally opened the door enough for them to see inside the office.

?

He didn't intend them to see inside the office... It was an accident...

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd stick to the 4th example. Sounds perfect to my non-native ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They're all correct and have your intended meaning.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd examples sound unnatural and wrong to me. **so** and **so that** just can't be there side by side with **accidentally** and **enough**.

Comment: No. It's incorrect to say that they *can't* be there. Read the comments to @BerryHolmes' question. The question was whether one could say it in these 4 ways and since they're technically correct, my answer stands.

Comment: Regarding #2, it reads: *He accidentally opened the door enough, so [therefore] they could see inside the office*.

Comment: Yes @LucianSava, it was because *He accidentally opened the door enough*. Why would you think it's intentional?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. +1.

Comment: All are grammatically correct (I think), but the use of **so** implies intentionality, which contradicts **accidentally**.  The only way I can see to make sense of this would usually be indicated by quotes in print and unusual phrasing when spoken, to indicate plausible deniability and intent. *He "accidentally" opened the door enough so they could see inside the office.*

Comment: Nope, they're not all correct and they don't all have the intended meaning. The "so" is syntactically and semantically superfluous.

Comment: @nigel222, so isn't contradicting accidentally here. It's quantifying the word enough. Without the word 'enough', what you suggested would apply, implying the word 'accidentally' was used sarcastically or that it was used incorrectly.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, one doesn't imply the other - the sentence is technically correct even with the superfluous so even though it might be against common usage

Comment: @Ash: We will have to agree to disagree. Because, no, it's not technically correct with the "so".

Comment: Looks like that'll be the case with almost all voters and commenters here who seem to not see that the second and fourth are correct sentences with the same meaning as the others, in fact, getting the questioner to believe this answer is wrong by popular vote.

Answer (score 12):

The first and the fourth sentences are the most correct. The fourth seems the most natural to me.

The problem with the second and third sentences is that the use of *so* implies that the man intentionally opened the door to let people see inside, which contradicts the use of *accidentally* to describe the action.

Comment: Indeed. Further, the only way to make the "so" even valid is to have a comma before it, which results in the meaning you describe; otherwise it's actually entirely misplaced.

Comment: Why imply intent at all? `He accidentally opened the door enough that they saw into the office`, keep it factual.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition In #2, if you add the comma, it doesn't imply intent, it's similar to saying "and as a result".

Comment: @Barmar: It acts in concert with the "enough".

Comment: @flith: Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

> He accidentally opened the door enough for them to see inside the office.

Seems to me the best possible way this sentence can be put. Saying "so that they could see inside the office" would imply that the door opening was *intentional* when it wasn't.

Comment: It would appear intentional if not for the word 'accidentally'.

Comment: @Ash True, but isn't "so that" used for giving a reason for an action? As in – "I bought a raincoat so that I can avoid getting drenched."

Comment: The word 'enough' in front of the 'so that' changes the usage of the rule you mentioned. In this case, the 'reason' was that door was opened enough for the action of them seeing inside the office to take place.

Comment: Without the word 'enough', what you suggested would apply, implying the word 'accidentally' was used sarcastically or that it was used incorrectly.

Comment: @Ash The usage of 'accidentally' sarcastically was the part where I was a little confused. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2):

Of your options, (1) and (4) would be readily understood without problem.

But the clearest way to put it is:

> He accidentally opened the door too wide, enough for them to see inside the office.

This precisely conveys the scope of the accident (opening the door too wide) and the consequence (it was wide enough for ...).

Comment: +1 I'd use this version. Even if it requires two sentences, the meaning is very clear.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: Technically, it's still one sentence, and can't be split neatly into two sentences without losing the continuity and cadence.